# Wordpress single post not showing content

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

My single-posts pages are not displaying any content. I have restored the original single.php from the theme but nothing changed.

Contents of single.php http://pastebin.com/ri6C96AX
Random post page  http://www.crossfitawac.com/onramp-6/

These posts are auto-published from Wodify. I've setup a blog-grid page in the WOD section that is showing the contents of each post, but if I want to see a single post from the website/blog page, the contents are not showing.

Comment: you can paste your code here on stackoverflow. other user will response better if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got a few issues in your single.php file. Remove `do_shortcode()` for your title- that is only for using [Shortcodes outside of the Content Editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode). Instead the Page title is displayed using:

```
 <?php the_title(); ?>
```

Inside your while loops, it's looking for a separate content template file. I'd recommend just starting with this and then after you get it working you could then consider moving it to it's own template.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```